# How do indie software developers test apps on devices they don't have

Tags: ios, testing, device, iphone-6-plus

I'm creating an app for Apple first. I'm creating it on every Apple device and I have friends/family who can let me borrow their devices so I can test my app. The only device that nobody I know has is an iPhone 6 PLUS. I have no idea how to get my hands on an iPhone 6 PLUS device. I tried going to Apple Store and asked if they had an iPhone6+ that's unhooked that I can borrow for 5 minutes, they said no. I have an iPhone 6 and it's the exact same app on iPhone 6+ so can I be safe to say it'll work exactly the same on iPhone 6 PLUS device as it does on iPhone 6?

Where can I find an iPhone 6 PLUS device to test if I don't know anyone who owns one and I i'm not going to buy one either b/c I just bought an iPhone 6?

Comment: I suspect most test on the simulator

Comment: There are services out there that have hundreds of real devices. You upload your project and let it run on the devices of your choice.

Comment: @Krumelur do you recommend any of these services?

Comment: @Crashalot: I'm a Microsoft/Xamarin employee, so my answer is biased: I recommend to look at Xamarin Testcloud https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud

Comment: @Krumelur not clear from Xamarin docs if you can test camera functionality on iphone 6 plus. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't test using the Simulator (i.e. camera functionality)?

That's the way most people do it, with wrappers around code (like camera functionality) so they can test most of the interfaces and make sure everything is working properly.

I still test on a physical 5s, but Simulator for everything else.

For example:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
```

(makes sure camera functions are available)

and

```
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
  ...
#endif
```

to block out functions that would not function/crash the Simulator.

Comment: simulator functions differently than device. Example is before I figured out how to do a shared banner mediation I implemented 2 different banners, one on each View Controller. On the simulator. Every time I went from one VC to another there would be a long pause and it'd glitch for a moment. On the device that never happened however, there was another ad issue that didn't occur on simulator. But then I figured out how to do shared banner mediation and now this never happens on both. Just an example between difference of testing on device and simulator. You can never be too sure.